# Values of function on plane, equilateral triangles.

Tags: functions, triangles

Given a function that outputs a real number for every point on the $XY$ plane, is it possible that for any equilateral triangle $XYZ$ the value $f(X)+f(Y)+f(Z)$ is equal to the perimeter of the triangle?

This is my idea:

The origin point has value $c$, lines at angles $2\pi/3, 4\pi/3, 0$ have value $kr-nc$ and $\pi/3, \pi, 5\pi/3$ have value $r(1-k)-n(1-c)$. Then, I determined the lines at angles $\pi/6, \pi/2, 5\pi/6, -5\pi/6, -\pi/2, -\pi/6$ have value $c$, because if you reflect the triangle $XYZ$ on points $(0,0), (r,0), (r, \pi/3)$ around the outer edge $YZ$, the new point $X'$ must be equal to $c$. Scaling down gives all six lines.

Finally I reflected $X'$ across the line with angle $0$ and got a new triangle $XX'X''$ that is also equilateral. Every point valued at $c$ but the perimeter isn't constant at $3c$ it changes depending on the sidelength.

---

But I feel like it may have logical errors. Can somebody determine if this is a rigorous proof or not?

Comment: Insofar as you have not defined what you mean by variables $k,n$, no it is not a rigorous proof.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the equilateral triangle ABC with perimeter $6$.

Let DEF be the equilateral triangle formed by the midpoints of the sides of ABC.

Assume $f$ is a perimeter function of the type hypothesised in the question.

Then

\begin{eqnarray}
f(A)+f(B)+f(C)&=&6\\
f(A)+f(D)+f(F)&=&3\tag{1}\\
f(E)+f(D)+f(F)&=&3\tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}

Subtacting equation 2 from equation 1 we see that $f(A)-f(E)=0$ so $f(A)=f(E)$.

By parallel arguments we see that $f(B)=f(F)$ and $f(C)=f(D)$.

Therefore $f(E)+f(F)+f(D)=f(A)+f(B)+f(C)=6$.

But the perimeter of triangle DEF is $3$. This is a contradiction.

Therefore no such perimeter function exists.

[image: Equilateral triangle partitioned into four smaller equilateral triangles]